Regex not match inside of match (validating content in Markdown links)
Ive been trying to create a PCRE regex (for grep -P) that returns matches where the content inside a match doesn't match the expected format.
The use case is grepping a directory of Markdown files, finding all (geo:) links, and returning any where the coordinate link does not match the expected format. But I can't figure out how to do the not match inside a match...
This regex works for the expected format:
[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)\)
And finding the (geo: string is easy.
But how can I do the not match inside the match?
Examples good format (that I don't want to return):

(https://url.com/something) Only looking for (geo:)
(geo:12.34567,-1234567)
(geo:50.5,25.5)

Invalid formats that I want to find:

(geo: 50.5,25.5) Space after :
(geo:Ooops typed text) Text instead of coordinates
(geo:12.34567 -12.34567) Space instead of comma
(geo:12.34567, -12.34567) Space after comma

I've tried variations of negative lookaheads on the desired matching format but I am not sure if that is a valid approach... Or if its even going to work.
(?!(?:([-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?))*?\)))
This question and answer got me close but I couldn't quite adapt it.
Regex to match local markdown links

Have you considered using Perl / Ruby / awk / Python? It would just be a lot easier to validate with those.

Yes, \(geo:(?!...) with the regex that matches the correct format should work.

Ok, that is what I thought should work... But it doesnt seem to be. My sample is [Place](geo:44.63995096078393,-12.0093) and a regex of \(geo:[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)\) does successfully match it. But the not match doesnt work with bad data.... Bad data like this [Place](geo:44.63995s096078393, -12.0093) which seems like it should match this regex \(geo:(?![-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?))\).

Even if I simplify it as far as I can with [Place](geo:12) this regex matches the clean data \(geo:(\d*)\) but flipping it doesnt work, sample data [Place](geo:w) and regex of \(geo:(?!\d*)\) results in no match on regex101.com and via bash.

With the negative lookahead \(geo:(?![-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)\)) See https://regex101.com/r/ulQZmo/1 and https://regex101.com/r/by0w0r/1 But note that this (geo:12.34567,-1234567) is not a valid match for your regex, as the second part of the regex after the comma does not match 7 digits like -1234567

Suppose you have these files:
$ head case[0-9].txt
==> case1.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (https://url.com/something) GOOD, Only looking for ( geo:) blah
Random text.
Something else

==> case2.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (geo:12.34567,-1234567) GOOD PATTERN blah
Random text.
Something else

==> case3.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (geo:50.5,25.5) GOOD PATTERN blah
Random text.
Something else

==> case4.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (geo: 50.5,25.5) BAD - Space after : blah
Random text.
Something else

==> case5.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (geo:Ooops typed text) BAD - Text instead of coordinates blah
Random text.
Something else

==> case6.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (geo:12.34567 -12.34567) BAD - Space instead of comma blah
Random text.
Something else

==> case7.txt <==
Random text.

Something else
Blah bla (geo:12.34567, -12.34567) BAD - Space after comma blah
Random text.
Something else

(So case4.txt - case7.txt are 'bad')
Rather than come up with some wizard level single PCRE, it is usually easier to filter out / validate what you WANT and then anything left over is what you DON'T WANT.
Here is a Ruby that demonstrates the concept:
ruby -e 'ARGV.each{|f| 
    paren_lines=File.open(f).each_line.
        select{|line| line=~/\(|\)/}.    # select only if it has parenthesis.
        reject{|line|                    # reject lines that are OK
            line=~/\(geo:[+-]?\d+\.?\d*,[+-]?\d+\.?\d*\)/ || line=~/\((?!geo:)/
        }
    puts "#{f} errors:\n\t#{paren_lines.join("\t")}\n" if paren_lines.length>0
}' case[0-9].txt

Prints:
case4.txt errors:
    Blah bla (geo: 50.5,25.5) BAD - Space after : blah

case5.txt errors:
    Blah bla (geo:Ooops typed text) BAD - Text instead of coordinates blah

case6.txt errors:
    Blah bla (geo:12.34567 -12.34567) BAD - Space instead of comma blah

case7.txt errors:
    Blah bla (geo:12.34567, -12.34567) BAD - Space after comma blah

You could do the same with Bash testing several greps but why? So much easier with awk / Perl / Python / Ruby. And awk is in every Unix.
Here is a more basic version that works in any awk:
awk '/[()]/{
    if (/\(geo:[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*,[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*/ ) next
    if (!/\(geo:/) next

    print FILENAME ": ", $0
    }
' case[0-9].txt

Prints:
case4.txt:  Blah bla (geo: 50.5,25.5) BAD - Space after : blah
case5.txt:  Blah bla (geo:Ooops typed text) BAD - Text instead of coordinates blah
case6.txt:  Blah bla (geo:12.34567 -12.34567) BAD - Space instead of comma blah
case7.txt:  Blah bla (geo:12.34567, -12.34567) BAD - Space after comma blah

Either the Ruby or the Awk could also further validate the acceptable pattern has a) balanced parenthesis (which is hard with regex alone) and b) numerically is in an acceptable range (again, challenging and error prone in a single regex).
The other advantage of this approach is that it easy to modify your conditions of what you want vs what you don't.

Thank you, that works! I should have thought of or looked at awk, I just assumed there should/would/could be a regex one liner that would do what I was aiming for... But awk wins again!
